# Want to create an app in which it shows 3 button vertically and horizontally at the center but when I have tried only the 3rd button was there ,

Tags: android

I want to create an app which shows 3 buttons but when I run my code it shows the third button not other ones have this code here -->

Here is my screenshot(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih3mK.png)

````
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


      <Button     
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="button1"        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

      <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="button2" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
       android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="button3" 
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>```
[enter image description here][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih3mK.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLjRr.png![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gM59v.png)![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRLj3.png)
````

Comment: add your ss of the desired layout that you want to get.

Comment: Can anybody help me

Comment: Read my comment m asking!

Comment: What is ss I don't know?

Comment: Show me your code

Comment: screenshot image of the desired output.

Comment: Read the body it is having link of screenshot

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ih3mK.png

Comment: Please tell me.

Comment: @TechGamerAnimator check my answer. I have replaced relative layout with LinearLayout and give oriental vertical. now if you want all button in center vertical then add "android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

Comment: Ok thanku but can you tell me why it is not happening in relative layout but in linear layout any reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I am sharing to show 3 Buttons horizontal and vertical with LinearLayout.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="b1" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="b2" />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="b3" />


        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="b4" />


    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="b5" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the screen shot I am attaching...[image]

Comment: if you find the answer right please mark it as right ! thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">


  <Button     
    android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"       
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="button1" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="button2" 
    />

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="button3" 
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanku pratik vekariya

Comment: @TechGamerAnimator if this my worked for you then could you please correct it?